# formatting to wstring simpler way of doing it

Tags: c++, wstring

I need to format a double. I use the code bellow

```
wstring to_wstring1(double f){
  wchar_t wc[0x40];swprintf(wc,countof(wc),L"%E",f);return wstring(wc);
}
```

Is there a way to do it that avoids using the buffer wc?
I am thinking to allocate a wstring with the size of the buffer and write there and after resize the string up to the final 0. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::to_wstring(double)`.

Note: It does require C++11

Comment: I don't mind using C++11. I already know to_wstring and it is for that that I named the function to_wstring1. But it doesn't accept format arguments ( I mean I want to format it using %E ).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::wostringstream w;
    w << 1.0;;
    std::wcout << w.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Note: It does not require C++11

Comment: : - ) neeeeed moaar characters